# android error android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a class with a sliding menu.
i get the following error when i resume on my activity,when the app is paused!

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment kostas.menu.rssreader.ListActivity$SampleListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Answer (score 0):

please notice the error message you got

> 06-05 16:27:04.215: E/AndroidRuntime(14976): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class kostas.menu.rssreader.ListActivity$SampleListFragment; no empty constructor

this kinda means you **HAVE** to have an empty constructor for every `Fragment` class you create.

just add the empty constructor and everything should be just fine.

Comment: you mean something like `public ListActivity(){}` ? this returns me the same error

Comment: no no no, the `Fragment` needs an empty constructor. add `public SampleListFragment(){};`

Comment: i have tried both of them and the error unfortunately remains..